# How to .SaveAs non-unique sent email to Windows folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have VBA code whose main functions are:

1. Load a form
2. Allow a user to choose a stock email response
3. Open a word document with the full response text
4. Create a reply using the text
5. Search the email and create a collection of strings containing corporate file numbers
6. Add the file numbers to an Excel list
7. Send the response

Now I want to save one copy of the sent item in a Windows folder, for each file number. I’ve been trying to wait until the item is sent and moved to Sent Items. The problem is that after calling the send method, the mailitem doesn’t send or move to Sent Items until after the code finishes so I end up in an infinite loop.

All the options I found involve using a class module and WithEvents. That would work if I wanted to copy every sent item to the folder. I can’t think of any criteria that would differentiate the emails created by this macro from normal emails. I could go into the Excel list of files, but that would bog everybody’s machine down on every send.

Is there a way to just have the email send find out when it has been sent and moved to sent items? My code to send, wait for it to go to sent items, and to save the emails is below. Note I have two global variables: cReply (Outlook.MailItem – the reply) and fNums (Collection – the file numbers).

I'm coding in Outlook 2016, but hope to move the module to Outlook 2010 at work.

```
Sub Send()
    Dim badChar As String
    badChar = "\/:*?™""® <>|.&@#_+`©~;-+=^$!,'" & Chr(34)
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim fName As String
    Dim inSentItems As Boolean
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim cSent As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim sentMoment As Date
    fName = cReply.Subject
    For x = 1 To Len(badChar)
        fName = Replace(fName, Mid(badChar, x, 1), "-")
    Next x
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFldr = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    inSentItems = True
    x = olFldr.Items.Count
    sentMoment = Now
    cReply.Send
    Do While olFldr.Items.Count <> x + 1
        If Now - sentMoment > TimeValue("0:00:10") Then
            inSentItems = False
            Exit Do
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    If inSentItems Then
        Set cSent = olFldr.Items(olFldr.Items.Count)
        For x = 1 To fNums.Count
            cSent.SaveAs sentFldrPth & fNums.Item(x) & " - " & fName & ".msg", olMSG
        Next x
        'cSent.Delete
    End If
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olFldr = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SaveSentMessageFolder to save to another folder.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868473.aspx

Monitor this other folder with ItemAdd code. You could move the mail to the Sent Items folder once done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea niton! I'm out of town this weekend but I'll give it a try early next week. Cheers!

Comment: Hi again @niton, follow-up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556260/application-startup-variable-disappears-after-sub-finishes that I put elsewhere rather than here as it's pretty big on its own. Let me know if you see where I'm going wrong. Thank you!

Comment: So this ended up working. It seems my problem was with either Outlook 2016 or SMTP email address. I've taken my code in the link above to work and it seems to be working.